# Am I misusing CakePHP's Text::tokenize utility?

Tags: php, cakephp, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize a search query, the way I'm calling the `Text::Tokenize` function is very similar to the [example on Cake's website](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/text.html#simple-string-parsing), but I'm running into a problem whenever I have a `"` with a `-` immediately in front of it.

```
$query = 'question "help needed" -"garbage" contents of query';
$tokens = Text::tokenize( $query, ' ', '"', '"');

foreach ( $tokens as $index => $token) {
    echo $token . "\n";
}
```

I get the following output.

```
question
"help needed"
-"garbage" contents of query
```

But, shouldn't I be getting the following instead? What am I missing?

```
question
"help needed"
-"garbage"
contents
of
query
```

It is worth noting, this does not occur for the query `'question -"garbage" contents of query'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't have anything to do with the `-` char, but with the occurrence of multiple left/right bounds. From the API description it's not clear whether the method is ment to support multiple boundaries, so I'd say it's either not supported, or it's a bug.

Having a quick look at the source I'd tend to say it's a bug, seems like it's maybe missing changing the `open` flag [**here**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.2/src/Utility/Text.php#L120-L122) (might not be the only problem though, or maybe not even part of the problem at all, I can't test it right now). In any case you may want to open an issue [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues), asking for an enhancement, respectively filing the behavior as a bug.